# How to increase python output lines in terminal ubuntu from an AWS instance?

Tags: 18.04, python3, aws

I have an AWS instance which I have connected to via ssh. I want to run my program $python3 -m program.py which works perfectly in the terminal.

But it only displays about 20 lines of output, and then the output in the start starts to disappear while more lines are coming in from below, but just the python code, not the ubuntu lines above.

I do not have an Ubuntu interface because it is an AWS instance, but I have access to its files and the terminal to fix the problem.

I have tested to use tmux and increase history lines option but it does not affect python output.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)**  What do you mean by "I do not have an Ubuntu interface because it is an AWS instance."?  `ssh` only access? `ftp` access? Something else entirely???

Comment: I have connected via SSH on PuTTYGEN. But I do not think that should matter on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting `HISTSIZE=10000 HISTFILESIZE=8000` in `.bashrc` and `.profile` in AWS?

Comment: Where can I find .bashrc and .profile? I do not think the problem is with AWS but with the ubuntu settings.

Comment: the `.bashrc` and `.profile` will be in your home directory which is `~/` or `/home/user/`